# compile error, variable not found in VBA

Tags: function, vba

I have the following code and I get the following error:
`Compile error, variable not found` (it is not able to find j)
Also, even though I provide MktVol as a vector of length 4, the message box returns `N=0`
Can you please help me fix my mistake.

```
Public Function EstimateAllParameters(params, MktStrike, MktVol, F, T, b)
Dim R As Double, a As Double, V As Double, N As Integer
Dim j as integer 'stops the compile error but the function returns #VALUE! 
Dim ModelVol() As Double, sqdError() As Double
R = params(1)
V = params(2)
a = params(3)
N = MktVol.Length
MsgBox ("N= " & N)
For j = 1 To N
 ModelVol(j) = Svol(a, b, R, V, F, MktStrike(j), T)
  sqdError(j) = (ModelVol(j) - MktVol(j)) ^ 2
Next j
EstimateAllParameters = Sum(sqdError)
End Function
```

`MktStrike` has the following values in cells E5:E8

```
12
13
14
15
```

and `MktVol` has the following values in cells F5:F8

```
0.234
0.236
0.242
0.249
```

Comment: You haven't dimmed `j` in that code. Also, what exactly are you passing in to `MktVol`?

Comment: I tried that and it was giving me #VALUE!, hence I tried to run without that. I am updating my initial post with the values I am passing to MktVol

Comment: A `Range` object doesn't have a `Length` property. Maybe you mean `MktVol.Cells.Count` ? You also need to ReDim your arrays to the correct size before you populate their values. And `Sum` is not a VBA function, but you can use `Application.Sum` instead.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks, that is indeed what I was trying to do. I will also reDim the arrays. I have been provided MatLab code and need to convert it to VBA. both of the languages I am still in the process of learning, so I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I made the fixes and that worked, so Thanks very much. I also need to find the row number of the smallest positive number in MktVol array. Is there an existing VBA application function I can use. The MatLab code I have for that is `index=find(MktVol>0)`. If I should make a separate post for this, please let me know and I can do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all values in MktVol will be positive, you can use `Application.Min(MktVol)` to find the minimum, and then `Application.Match(v, MktVol, 0)` to find the position of that value (v) in MktVol

Answer (score 0):

Obvious issue is J hasn't been Dim'd

I would change:

```
Dim R As Double, a As Double, V As Double, N As Integer
```

To

```
Dim R As Double, a As Double, V As Double, N As Integer, J as Integer
```